# html5 canvas image crop with soft edges

Tags: html, canvas

I have followed this (https://github.com/netplayer/crop) repository and created the image cropping tool with some changes. When I crop the image using the pattern and lines, the images are cropped with the jagged edges. How can I remove the jagged edges and apply some shadow around the images like feather feature in Photoshop.Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2y888wgr/)

Here is the relevant portion of my code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var points=[];
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    var offset = $('#myCanvas').offset();
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2) {
        var x = parseInt(jQuery.trim(points[i]));
        var y = parseInt(jQuery.trim(points[i + 1]));
        if (i == 0) {
            ctx.moveTo(x - offset.left, y - offset.top);
        } else {
            ctx.lineTo(x - offset.left, y - offset.top);
        }



    }
    ctx.restore();
    var pattern = ctx.createPattern(imageObj, "repeat");
    ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
    ctx.fill();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here's one way using compositing and shadowing:**

- Create a masking image from your path. The mask is your user's filled path with edges that have been feathered using shadowing.  The image below is a mask shaped like a star--notice the feathered edges that were creating with shadowing.

[image]

- Draw the mask on the canvas.
- Set compositing to 'source-in' which causes any new drawing to only be drawn where the existing pixels are not transparent.
- Draw your car image on the canvas.  Thanks to compositing, the image will be drawn only inside the user's path and will also be feathered just like the mask.

[image]

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var fadeLength=20;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/car.jpg";
function start(){

  var mask=document.createElement('canvas');
  var mctx=mask.getContext('2d');

  canvas.width=mask.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=mask.height=img.height;

  mctx.translate(-500,0);

  mctx.shadowColor='black';
  mctx.shadowOffsetX=500;
  mctx.shadowOffsetY=0;
  mctx.shadowBlur=fadeLength;

  drawStar(mctx,150,120,5,90,30);
  drawStar(mctx,150,120,5,90,30);

  mctx.translate(500,0);

  ctx.drawImage(mask,0,0);

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-in'
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

}


function drawStar(ctx,cx,cy,spikes,outerRadius,innerRadius){
  var rot=Math.PI/2*3;
  var x=cx;
  var y=cy;
  var step=Math.PI/spikes;

  ctx.strokeSyle="#000";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(cx,cy-outerRadius)
  for(i=0;i<spikes;i++){
    x=cx+Math.cos(rot)*outerRadius;
    y=cy+Math.sin(rot)*outerRadius;
    ctx.lineTo(x,y)
    rot+=step

    x=cx+Math.cos(rot)*innerRadius;
    y=cy+Math.sin(rot)*innerRadius;
    ctx.lineTo(x,y)
    rot+=step
  }
  ctx.lineTo(cx,cy-outerRadius)
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; padding:10px;}
canvas{border:1px solid red; background-color:black;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Is this still the best approach in 2020? Thanks for your help!